# how to set Input value in formField ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

i cannot able to set value to the Inputfield in Form. below is my code. even i tried to give direct value too like in `value='ABC'` in input element. but no luck. when i tried to display value outside Form Tag like

```
<h1>{this.state.company.companyCode}</h1>
```

this shows value. but not inside Form.

```
    class UpdateCompany extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            companycode: { value: ''},
            company: ''
            };
            this.loadCompanydetail = this.loadCompanydetail.bind(this);        
        }

        loadCompanydetail(companyid) {
            GetCompanyById(companyid)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    company: response
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                if(error.status === 404) {
                    this.setState({
                        notFound: true,
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        serverError: true,
                        isLoading: false
                    });        
                }
            });        
        }

        componentDidMount(){        
            const companyid =this.props.match.params.companyId;
            this.loadCompanydetail(companyid);
        }

        render() {
            const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form

            return (
                    <h1 className="page-title">Edit Company - {this.state.company.companyCode}</h1>

                        <Form>
                            <Form.Item label="Company Code">
                                {getFieldDecorator('companycode', {
                                    rules: [
                                      {
                                        required: true,
                                        message: 'Please enter Code',
                                        max: 3,
                                      },
                                    ],
                                  })(<Input name="companycode" value={this.state.company.companyCode} />)}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ span: 12, offset: 6 }}>
                                <Button type="primary" 
                                    htmlType="submit" 
                                    size="large">Submit</Button>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Form>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you're using Ant-Design. Could you please include your imports, tag question and adjust title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems a little hit and miss. From my understanding, you are trying to set the value of the input field as the user types in. You need to use the **onChange** event handler with the input field. Also, I would suggest you to not use nested objects inside the state. Here's a simple approach

```
state = {
    companyCode: ''
 };
```

Now, Inside your render function for the input field you need to use a onChange handler:

```
<input type="text" name="companyCode" value={this.state.companyCode} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

You can define the handleChange function outside the render function. Also, you can use arrow functions to avoid binding to this. Here's an example:

```
handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ companyCode: e.target.value });
}
```

Learn more about [events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) in react.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your `Input` component is designed, but it seems that you are passing an object as the `value`.

You set `companyCode` as an object:

```
companycode: { value: ''}
```

So you should use it like this:

```
value={this.state.company.companyCode.value}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two-way binding `getFieldDecorator` from `antd` will not work for nested state (`company.companyCode`). You can find documentation on https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.create(options)

Try assigning and using `companyCode` with `setFieldsValue`.

```
  setFieldsValue({
    companyCode: response.companyCode,
  });
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-dubinsky-ln4yu?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks for your idea. actually the value is displaying if i use just input tag inside form.item.   but if i use {getFieldDecorator} then the value is not displaying...

Comment: also if i try to edit value. the value is not changing... even i create handlechange function. seems like the displaying db value is considering as object in input value.

Comment: My bad. `setFieldsValue`, not `setState`. Updated. Remember you don't have to use form library from Ant. You can just save values in state or add something like Formik or React-Final-Form.

Comment: Thnaks, i achieved this action using... clear the state of datasource and call the dataload function inside handleDelete function.